# Can principal components changed by a normalization method be used to construct original data shape with SVD

Tags: pca, normalization, svd, back-transformation, batch-normalization

I'm planning to use an algorithm called [Harmony](https://github.com/immunogenomics/harmony), designed for data normalization, particularly in the context of single cell data analysis. Harmony operates by taking principal components (*PC*s) as input and outputting corrected principal components (*PC'*).

Typically, Harmony is applied to the top *k* ranks of *PC*s to correct for batch effects or other sources of variability. However, I would like retain the original data structure post-normalization. To do this I would input all PCs generated from my dataset into Harmony. I would use singular value decomposition (SVD) to generate all possible principal components.

The SVD of a matrix *A* can be represented as:

$$
A = U S V^T
$$

Here, *U* and *V* are orthogonal matrices, while *S* is a diagonal matrix containing the singular values. To create the *PC*s, I would multiply *U S* and not perform a *k-rank* approximation subsetting the *PC*s as all methods i've seen that use harmony.

These *PC*s would input to harmony which produces the output *PC'*.

$$
PC \rightarrow Harmony \rightarrow PC'
$$

After processing through Harmony, and acquiring the normalized PCs (PC'). My assumption is that the normalized component PC' can equivalently be represented as the product of modified matrices *U'* and *S'*, implying:

$$
PC' \equiv U'S' \equiv (US)'
$$

The ultimate goal is to reconstruct the original dataset in its normalized form, which I assume can be achieved by:

$$
(US)' V^T = A'
$$

My questions to the community are:

1. Given Harmony normalizes the PCs (PC -> PC'), is it mathematically sound to equate the normalized PCs (PC') to $(US)'$ and then use this to reconstruct the original data matrix in its normalized form, as in $(US)' V^T = A'$?
2. Are there any conceptual or mathematical flaws in my approach to using all PCs for normalization with Harmony and subsequently reconstructing the dataset?